# Webgl sylvester.js glUtils.js permission

Tags: javascript, webgl, libraries

Am learning to use webgl and I was following the [mozzila tutorials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebGL/Adding_2D_content_to_a_WebGL_context#See_also)
While I was, I found out that it was using sylvester.js and glUtils.js. My question is are they open source and free to use? I dont want to run into legal issues if I make a game with them and places ads. I tried googling them but I can't find out anything about their license, please dont downvote I tried to do research

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sylvester.js is released under the MIT license (see http://sylvester.jcoglan.com/)
As for glutils.js, "Nobody seems entirely clear on where it came from" according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebGL/Adding_2D_content_to_a_Web

Comment: Thanks for answering this questions, it been so long that I asked this am glad someone finally answered it :D